# Unicode name from Char

Tags: haskell, unicode

I'm looking for a function that takes a Char as input and gives the unicode name of that code point (`::Char->String`), but I couldn't find any results on Hoogle.  I assume that there is no builtin (If there is, please let me know) and so I wonder what's the best way to write this function and its inverse (`::String->Maybe Char`).

I know you'd have to read [UnicodeData.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/7.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt) or a similar document, but I don't know what the best/fastest function would be.

Answer (score 4):

The [unicode-names package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unicode-names) contains the function

```
getCharacterName :: Char -> String
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! How would you write the inverse function, though? (`::String -> Maybe Char`)

Comment: @Zaq Flip each element in `theList` here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unicode-names-3.2.0.0/docs/src/Data-Char-Properties-NamesData.html#getCharacterName and write a similar function (perhaps this should be added to the lib)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thanks to @TwanVanLaarhoven who provided an excellent answer.  I did however need a function that did the reverse of `getCharacterName`.
What I originally wanted was a function that would read the file and not have it hard-coded, but I eventually realized that that would require unsafe IO operations.
What I decided to do was to copy [UnicodeData.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/7.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt) into notepad++ and use the following regex replacements:

write `module UnicodeNames (characterToName,nameToCharacter) where`

paste [UnicodeData.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/7.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt)

replace this: `^([\dA-F]+);([^<;>]+).*$|^([\dA-F]+);(?:[^;]*;){9}([^<;>]+).*$`

with this: `characterToName '\\x$1$3' = "$2$4"`

append `characterToName _ = ""`

paste again

replace this (again): `^([\dA-F]+);([^<;>]+).*$|^([\dA-F]+);(?:[^;]*;){9}([^<;>]+).*$`

with this: `nameToCharacter "$2$4" = Just '\\x$1$3'`

append `nameToCharacter _ = Nothing`

replace `^.*<.*$` with nothing to remove extra lines.

The file will be incredibly long and take forever to compile :-)  In addition to having an inverse function, this method has the advantage of providing more names than the unicode-names package by using unicode 1.0 names as well.  The two functions in this file rely on pattern matching to act as a dictionary from char to string and vice-versa.  I would put my solution on PasteBin or somewhere else if it didn't use a ton of memory.